# How to install TimeManager for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I'm trying to install [TimeManager for QGIS](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/). I can't find it under Plugins/Fetch Python Plugins and I have verified that the official repository is listed in the Plugins menu, so I'm wondering if there's some other way that I'm supposed to install it. Underdark, am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TimeManager is an "experimental" plugin. Make sure you have checked the "Show all plugins, even those marked as experimental" box in the Options tab of the Plugin Installer.

[image]